# Use "find" command to list files IN specified directory

Tags: linux, unix, find, perl

I'm putting together a perl script, and I'm using the following command to list all files and directories under a specified directory

```
`find $dir -print`
```

This lists all files and directories **UNDER** directory $dir. I simply want something that will output files and directories directly under or **IN** directory $dir, **using the find command**.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `find` command?  Why not just use Perl's built-in `opendir` and `readdir` functions?

Comment: @KeithThompson Too late now, it was written, it cannot be unwritten...

Comment: Perhaps I can recommend a few text editors with "delete" features.

Comment: @KeithThompson delete...never heard of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` before any other predicates to restrict it to items located directly within the search directory.